# SDK Version Issue on iOS testflight

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, react-native, testflight

I'm trying to initiate the testflight for my iOS application, suddenly I'm started getting the below error

"SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 13.2 SDK. All iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 14 SDK or later, included in Xcode 12 or later."

After googling a bit, I found that few people are facing the same and like other developers, I don't want to upgrade the xcode as many other applications are dependent on it and I am using xcode 11.0.1 and to upgrade the xcode to higher version, I need to upgrade my macOS as well, I am using mojave and I have to upgrade it to Bigsur.

As I'm a cross-platform developer, I have very little idea about these processes, so please help  with a proper solution

Comment: I encountered this issue a few months ago and a solution I found was to have multiple versions of xcode at the same time (so you will have to update your os), but you won't have to give up to any older versions of xcode. In order to obtain this, you only have to download the dmg corresponding to the newer version of xcode you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upgrade is compulsary and I have to go with it